# What can I say about an $E_\infty$ ring spectrum with an odd invertible element?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, ring-spectra

I have an $E_\infty$ ring spectrum $R$. I suspect it is trivial, but I'm not sure. What I do know is that there is an $R$-linear equivalence $R \simeq \Sigma R$. Unless I am very confused, this already implies, for example, that $\pi_* R$ is a $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra.

What else does a condition like $R \simeq \Sigma R$ imply? For example, does it imply statements about, say, the action of Steenrod operators?

I am also interested in statements that require extra niceness conditions on this equivalence, because in my case I understand the equivalence reasonably well and can try to check for specific niceness conditions.

Comment: Sorry can you share the argument that it is linear over F2? I can only see that 2 can't be invertible

Comment: MO is an E_{infinity}-algebra with homotopy groups a polynomial ring over F_2.  If you invert a polynomial generator in odd degree, I think you get a non-trivial ring of the sort you are describing.  What you can say if 2=0 in pi_0 of an E_{infinity} ring is that the ring receives an E_2-ring map from F_2, and in particular is an F_2 module spectrum.  This means the cohomology with Steenrod action is determined from the homotopy groups, and vice versa.

Comment: @davik : if $x$ is invertible in odd degree, then $x^2$ is invertible, and also $2$-torsion ($x^2 = (-1)^{|x|} x^2 = -x^2$), therefore $2  = 0$

Comment: @JeremyHahn Cool. Do you want to expand your comment into an answer? Definitely $R \simeq \Sigma R$ is not enough to imply $R \simeq 0$. For example, take the strictly-commutative algebra $\mathbb{F}_2[t^{\pm 1}]$ with $t$ of degree 1.

Comment: Doesn't Jeremy's comment mean that $R$ is $H(A[t^\pm])$ for some (discrete) $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra $A$?

Comment: @kiran : this seems to require that it receives a map from its $\pi_0$, and I'm  not sure how that follows - am I missing some other argument ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi good point thanks, I guess my statement is just at the level of $H\mathbb{F}_2$-modules.